# Error installing or updating due to dpkg and linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic

Tags: dpkg

I have tried searching and found many articles, posts, and discussions around this error but I have yet to find anything that tells me how to fix it.

---

I have run the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (3.11.0-15.25) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

Setting up linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (3.11.0-15.25) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (3.11.0-15.25) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm at a loss and do not know where to go from here.

Any help you could provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what was the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: The output of uname -r
3.11.0-15-generic

Comment: did you able to install any package via `apt-get`?

Comment: And also provide the output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic`.

Comment: I am not able to install anything using apt-get... I get this error every time also the output of the apt-cache policy linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 3.11.0.15.16
  Candidate: 3.11.0.17.18
  Version table:
     3.11.0.17.18 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main i386 Packages
 *** 3.11.0.15.16 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.11.0.12.13 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages

Comment: Run this command `apt-get download linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic`

Comment: apt-get download linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic
Get:1 Downloading linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic 3.11.0-17.31 [14.1 MB]
Fetched 14.1 MB in 2min 1s (117 kB/s)

Comment: Then run this `apt-get download linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic`

Comment: apt-get download linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic
Get:1 Downloading linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic 3.11.0-17.31 [1,061 kB]
Fetched 1,061 kB in 1s (638 kB/s)

Comment: run `sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic`

Comment: sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic

Comment: run `sudo dpkg -i /home/$USER/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic`

Comment: sudo dpkg -i /home/$USER/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic
dpkg: error processing /home/don/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/don/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic
don@Assassin:~$ ls /home/$USER/linux*
/home/don/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic_3.11.0-17.31_i386.deb
/home/don/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic_3.11.0-17.31_i386.deb

Comment: please post the path where the downloaded files are located.

Comment: run `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the/file/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic`

Comment: don@Assassin:~$ ls -al /home/don/linux*
-rw-r--r-- 1 don don  1060924 Feb  5 13:36 /home/don/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic_3.11.0-17.31_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 don don 14119470 Feb  5 13:36 /home/don/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic_3.11.0-17.31_i386.deb

Comment: sudo dpkg -i /home/don/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic_3.11.0-17.31_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic.
(Reading database ... 218780 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic_3.11.0-17.31_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic:
 linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic depends on linux-headers-3.11.0-17; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.11.0-17 is not installed.

Comment: dpkg: error processing linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic